# Is there a way to access varargs without specifying default value arguments in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, argument-passing

```
def foo(a=MyComplexObject(), b=Something(), *args):
    print a, b, args
```

Is there a way to call `foo` with specifying *args and *not* specifying a or b in the function call - thus using there default values?

Something like

```
foo(*args=(1,2,3))
```

This is purely out of curiosity.

Comment: IIRC, in this example `a` & `b` are only instantiated once,so it's the same as `default_a = MyComplexObject()` , `def foo(a=default_a):`; args come before kwargs in python 2.7 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to move your keyword arguments to a variable keyword capture too:

```
def foo(*args, **kw):
    a = kw.get('a', MyComplexObject())
    b = kw.get('b', b=Something())
    print a, b, args
```

Python will fill the two keyword arguments *first* otherwise, as in Python 2 there is no way to specify that these keywords cannot be filled by positional arguments.

Python 3 [changed the interpretation of the positional catchall parameter](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) to make this possible without forcing you to use the `**` keyword parameter catch-all.

If you cannot change the function definition yourself or upgrade to Python 3, then your only recourse is to specify the defaults again, or retrieve them from the function (using the [`inspect.getargspec()` convenience function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec)):

```
import inspect

defaults = inspect.getargspec(foo).defaults
foo(*(defaults + (1,2,3)))
```

`defaults` here is a tuple of the keyword argument default values.

Demonstration:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def foo(a='spam', b='foo', *args):
...     print a, b, args
... 
>>> defaults = inspect.getargspec(foo).defaults
>>> foo(*(defaults + (1,2,3)))
spam foo (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Does not answer my question.
I can not change the function signature or what is inside of the function.

Comment: @mkorpela: That is how you'll have to do it to make this work.

Comment: @mkorpela then you have to do: `foo(MyComplexObject(), Something(), *(1, 2, 3))

Comment: I haven't got access to the default values.